# Central limit theorem for sum of samples?

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

The CLT(central limit theorem) states
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} 
$$
conforms standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$, i.e. $\bar{x}$ coincides with $N(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Why I could not say that $n\bar{x}$ will have maximum probability at $n\mu$ which equals to $$NormPDF_{(n\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})}(n\mu)$$

(*NormPDF is normal distribution probability density function*)

Since $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k =n\bar{x}
$$But actually $n\bar{x}$ conforms $N(\mu,\sqrt{n}\sigma)$ which is a more flat bell curve and $$NormPDF_{(n\mu, \sqrt{n}\sigma)}(n\mu)< NormPDF_{(n\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})}(n\mu)$$So why just scaling the random variable will have effect to its probability or probability density function?

Comment: This has so many typos that it is difficult to understand. If the distribution is wider, then there’s less probability of finding it near the middle... what is strange about that? The probabilities need to add to one... if you make the distribution wider, you better decrease its height.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks. If only consider exact one point **x** on the x-axis it also have a probability which is f(x)dx, this is a infinite small number, when multiply this x value by n, the new value **nx** will have same probability f(x)dx in some random experiments and I also notice that if so the **nx**'s distribution will become descrete.